# Convert integer array to string array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like below:

```
var sphValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

then I need to convert above array like as below one:

```
var sphValues = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
```

How can I convert?
I used this for auto-complete.

Comment: `sphValues.map(String)`

Comment: @elclanrs You should post that as an answer and not a comment

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5].toString().split(",")`

Comment: @SonalPM You should refer markdown as you are having a hard time to post a comment with a link, cuz you posted and deleted your comment 4 times, now 5

Answer (score 301, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and pass the [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) constructor as a function, which will turn each number into a string:

```
sphValues.map(String) //=> ['1','2','3','4','5']
```

This will not mutate sphValues. It will return a new array.

Comment: For older browsers which do not support Array.map, you can use underscore.js: _.map(sphValues, String)

Comment: Unfortunately, this will also convert booleans to strings.

Answer (score 17):

just by using array methods

```
var sphValues = [1,2,3,4,5];   // [1,2,3,4,5] 
sphValues.join().split(',')    // ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Answer (score 13):

Use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
var strArr = arr.map(function(e){return e.toString()});
console.log(strArr); //["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

**Edit:**
   Better to use `arr.map(String);` as @elclanrs mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Why and not just toString() ?

Answer (score 6):

```
for(var i = 0; i < sphValues.length; i += 1){
    sphValues[i] = '' + sphValues[i];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `.map()` at this context that is a better move, as well as you can do like the below code this would add more readability to your code,

```
sphValues.map(convertAsString);

function convertAsString(val) {
  return val.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## ES6 solution

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10];
// bugfix: the `10` edge case
const strs = Array.from(nums, x => `${x}`);
console.log(strs);
// ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '10']
```

> git diff

```
-  const strs = Array.from(nums.join(``));
+  const strs = Array.from(nums, x => `${x}`);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can just append a '' to convert it to a string type.

```
var sphValues = [1,2,3,4,5];
for(var itr = 0; itr<sphValues.length;itr++){
  sphValues[itr] = '' + sphValues[itr];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 var value;
 for (var i = 0; i < data3.sph.length; i++) {
     value = data3.sph[i];
     //sphValues[i] = data3.sph[i];
     var obj = {
         label: value
     };
     sphValues.push(obj);
 }
```

You can use this method for auto complete. I think your problem will be solved, but it will not convert like you want, it will convert like

```
["label": "val1", "label": "val2"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution using map:

```
let nums = [1,2,2,4,3,2,5,6]
let all_to_str = nums.map(num => {return num.toString()})
console.log(all_to_str)
```

Output:

> [   '1', '2', '2',   '4', '3', '2',   '5', '6' ]

Answer (score -1):

just by using the array.map method, you can convert an array of numbers into an array of string

```
var sphValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const numberToStringArray = sphValues.map((number) => {
return number.toString();
});
console.log(numberToStringArray); //['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```