# Convert array values into strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have this array [ABC, QWE, XYZ]
I would like to turn it into ['ABC', 'QWE', 'XYZ']

When I try to manipulate values in the current array I get: `ReferenceError: ABC is not defined`

Any ideas on how should I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: `'ABC'` is a String. What is `ABC` ?

Comment: Hey Ans, thanks for your help. it's just something I copy pasted but needs to be a string to manipulate in my script.

Comment: @QuentinDel so you may have an array like: [1,2,3] containing numbers and you want to turn it into : ['1', '2', '3'] is that a more appropriate example?

Comment: Hey Samuil, yes why not.

Comment: Can you show us your code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert integer array to string array in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624166/convert-integer-array-to-string-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't do that directly but after little bit change you can do that...
So the current array you said like array [ABC, QWE, XYZ],

Lets design you keys in object first:

```
var obj = {
ABC:1, QWE:'somevalue', XYZ:new Date()
}
```

So I created object obj having your variables lets say the three variables, now lets convert:

```
var arr = [];

for (var key in obj){
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
    arr.push(String(key));
}
```

console.log(arr);// you will see the desire result.

Running example here : [example](https://jsfiddle.net/r38yystr/1/)

Answer (score 10):

Convert arrays element types:
Number to strings

```
    var strArr = [1,2,3,4,5].map(String);
    // Result: ["1","2","3","4","5"]
```

Comment: Why does this work?