# creating a string with array values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array. I need to create a string with the values in the array.
Eg: array = [100,200,300]
the string should look like '100'',''200'',''300'

any quick suggestions?

Regards
Giri

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert integer array to string array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624166/convert-integer-array-to-string-array-in-javascript)

Comment: A string with `"100", "200", "300"` or a string like: `100,200,300`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var array = [100, 200, 300];
var str = array.join(',');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

`const myString = array.join(',')`

This will join each element in the array with a `,` delimiter.

EDIT:

To get quotes in your string, to match the `"100","200","300" pattern, use:

`const myString = array.join('","');`

Comment: array.join("'',''")